# Search Results hidden for questions with 'javascript' in criteria

Tags: support, ignored-tags, search

Searching for questions with 'javascript' in the criteria are hidden in the Search Results.

Examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=thing1+javascript+thing2

Known browsers with this problem:
Chrome
IE 8

Comment: I'm not replicating this on IE8. How exactly are these hidden? Are you receiving no results at all?

Comment: No repro in either FF 3.6 or IE7. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Do you have javascript in your ignored tags?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, If you have `java*` in the ignored tag and choose **Hide Ignored Tags** in pref, you won't see javascript posts too.

- Turn off **Hide Ignored Tags** checkbox
- or put `java`, `java-*` in ignored tag

Answer (score 1):

Ack. I had 'java*' as an ignored tag.

Comment: Then you will surely not see javascript too, `*` is wildcard and all the tag startswith `java` will get ignored.