# 0 search results for posts containing "this" tagged with `javascript`

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

[No results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript%20this&submit=search0)?! I find that highly unlikely!

[I do not have `java*` as an ignored tag.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50471/search-results-hidden-for-questions-with-javascript-in-criteria)

Comment: possible duplicate: [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5685/why-cant-you-search-for-where](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5685/why-cant-you-search-for-where)

Comment: You're not searching for questions tagged with [tag:javascript] but the word itself. I don't know why it wasn't automatically converted to a tag search. I suspect it has something to do with `this` being a common word.

Comment: "this" is a stop word in the search engine, we'll take a look at this coming up, but that's not an easy fix (it worsens many other scenarios).

Comment: @NickCraver: OK. Understandably a tricky one.

Comment: @Scrooge: [Actually there was no difference either way.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+this&submit=search)

Comment: I think I need a lesson 1 on stop words. Shouldn't `this` just be eliminated from the search resulting in a search for `javascript` (with thousands of results)?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal : Stack Overflow's search converts popular tag names to tag searches. So it's probably literally the same search with or without the tag explicitly marked in the query.

Comment: @NickCraver : Shouldn't be that hard for the results page to mention that it removed the stop word from the query, no? Then, at least, the user would understand *why* the search failed. I understand the fix itself can be tricky. Having said that, I'm not sure that `this` should be a stop word at all on a programming site.

Comment: @Craig - The engine isn't only running for SO :) Also, no, it's non-trivial to show the word was removed, but we'll be taking a look either way.

Comment: @NickCraver You don't need to know that the word was removed from the query. You just need the intersection of the query words and the list of all stop words (which I'm presuming, perhaps incorrectly, that you know).

Answer (score 3):

Your *exact* case isn't solved, because `this` is still a stop word.  You'll need to quote it to ensure it doesn't get removed, like this:

```
 javascript "this"
```

You can [test it out here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+%22this%22)